# Css classes created on the fly are showed without new line on Firefox style editor

Tags: javascript, css

So .. it is very difficult to review something ...
(because I see a long one unique line of data-....)

`.blue0 {color:#00ffff;} .back_blue0 {background-color:#00ffff;} .line_blue0 {clear: both;position: relative; height: 1px;;background-color:#00ffff;} .border_blue0 {border:1px solid #00ffff;} .hover_bo_blue0:hover {border:1px solid #00ffff;} .hover_ba_blue0:hover {border:1px solid #00ffff;} .border_r_blue0 {border-right:1px solid #00ffff;} .border_l_blue0 {border-left:1px solid #00ffff;} .border_t_blue0 {border-top:1px solid #00ffff;} .border_b_blue0 {border-bottom:1px solid #00ffff;} .blue1 {color:#00ccff;} .back_blue1 {background-color:#00ccff;} .line_blue1 {clear: both;position: relative; height: 1px;;background-color:#00ccff;} .border_blue1 {border:1px solid #00ccff;} .hover_bo_blue1:hover {border:1px solid #00ccff;} .hover_ba_blue1:hover {border:1px solid #00ccff;} .border_r_blue1 {border-right:1px solid #00ccff;} .border_l_blue1 {border-left:1px solid #00ccff;} .border_t_blue1 {border-top:1px solid #00ccff;} .border_b_blue1 {border-bottom:1px solid #00ccff;} .blue2 {color:#0099ff;} .back_blue2 {background-color:#0099ff;} .line_blue2 {clear: both;position: relative; height: 1px;;background-color:#0099ff;} .border_blue2 {border:1px solid #0099ff;} .hover_bo_blue2:hover {border:1px solid #0099ff;}`

I create my classes using the code

```
my_css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a_style));
```

I have played with the possibility of adding `\n` or `<br/>` to a_style (css data) without success.

However I can view this data rightly in Chrome.

Any trick would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just run it in a CSS beautifier?

Comment: @civiltomain Let me precisely ask, what you mean. You create the CSS classes with JavaScript and append it to an existing link stylesheet element? And then you want to inspect the resulting CSS? IS this correct?

But what type of inspection do you make? In the browser? Whcih browser?

Comment: how about `/n/r` new line and carriage return

Comment: lol @editor who formatted the question, the whole point was to show that OP sees it all in one line, formatting it breaks the question's point

Comment: Can you show the exact code with which you tried adding an `\n`? I made a fiddle that shows it works: http://jsfiddle.net/tLb6J/ where you can see that the `\n` becomes visible in the result, so I'm afraid you've done something wrong.

Comment: Solved. The fix is that it is needed to add \n to the text you write inside () of createTextNode function. I had adding it out of the ().... Thanks for your time....

Comment: @Banana LOL indeed. Fixed.